# Easier way to pass multiple parameters in a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dry, simplify

This is a JavaScript function that determines if arguments are strings

just curious if anyone has a way to simplify this function?
I can't help but think there is since there are so many similarities in the parameters

typeof x === "string"

that there is a way to simplify it. I asked my teachers and they told me they were unaware of any.

```
function isString(string1, string2, string3) {
        if (typeof x === "string" && typeof y === "string" && typeof z === "string")
        console.log("Yes!" + x + " " + y + " " + z)
        else {
          console.log("Nope!")
        }
      }

      isString("String1", "String2", "String3")
```

I really look forward to reading your responses!

Thanks
-Joe

Comment: Does your function need to take exactly three strings? There are ways to make it more generic by having it take an arbitrary amount of strings.

Comment: Should that be `string1`/`string2`/`string3` instead of `x`/`y`/`z`?

Comment: I would use a rest param with the arguments, use `args.every`, and pass a custom function which checks if the item is a string.

Comment: You could send an array of strings too.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) or the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that let you handle an arbitrary amount of arguments, together with looping over them (or using [a helper method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for that):

```
function areStrings(...args) {
    if (args.every(x => typeof x === "string"))
        return "Yes!" + args.join(" ");
    else
        return "Nope!";
}

console.log(areStrings("String1", "String2", "String3"));
console.log(areStrings(5, "someString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can receive your params as an array o, and the use functional parameter to check:

```js
function isString(...strings) {
  if (strings.every(s => typeof s === 'string'))
     console.log("They are string")
  else
     console.log("They are not string")
}
```

Comment: Yeah my bad, i'll  change the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if multiple variables are strings, you can use this function:

```
function isString(...args){
  for(var i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
    if(typeof args[i] !== 'string'){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

You can pass as much parameters as you want and the result will be only true if all parameters are strings.

Example:

- `isString(4)` returns `false`
- `isString("Hello World")` returns    `true`
- `isString("I am a string", 3, true, "Hello")` returns `false`
- `isString("Hello World", "Welcome")` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

Clear answer, simple effective. I come to propose another way of doing things. Arrow function + ternary. More verbose but condense.
(I didn't know every cool :))

```
var resultAmeliored = (...args) => 'Var: '+args.map(val => val+' is '+typeof val).join(', ');

var areStrings = (...args)=>args.every(s => typeof s === 'string')?true:false;

console.log(areStrings("String1", "String2", "String3"));
//true
console.log(resultAmeliored(5, "someString"));
//"Var: 5 is number, someString is string"
```